# Ошибка C++ , консоль

Tags: c++

Решил попробовать себя в c++, но первая проблема не дает мне покоя

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

ошибка

```
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Users\kolya\source\repos\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe". Символы загружены.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
"Project2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll". Невозможно найти или открыть PDB-файл.
Поток 0x4954 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
Поток 0x1fa4 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
Поток 0x50e0 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
Программа "[2584] Project2.exe" завершилась с кодом 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Быстро сворачивается Консоль

Answer (score 4):

Ничего страшного. Студия просто не нашла pdb файлы, но Вам врядли нужно отлаживать внутренние библиотеки.

А что бы окно консоли не закрывалось быстро, просто запускайте через Ctrl+F5.

Либо пойдите по "известному в интернете пути" и просто добавьте в самый конец `system("pause");`.

И ещё способ - поставить точку останова на `return 0;` - в больших проектах конечно долго, но в студенческих поделках - самое оно.

И мой любимый - открыть консоль отдельно и запускать в ней самостоятельно.  Но это на любителя.

Comment: все равно консоль закрывается

Comment: даже после sysnte("pause"); ? не верю

Comment: @JustTerrora, `system("pause")` необходимо писать перед `return 0;`

Comment: В нынешней версии Visual Studio окно больше не закрывается само, даже при запуске через просто F5. Чтобы оно закрывалось, надо идти специально указывать опцию в настройках отладчика. То есть назойливой  проблемы `system("pause")` больше нет. Обновите студию.

Comment: А можно сделать , чтобы все работало без CTRL+F5 или system('pause'), как раньше ?

Comment: @AnT все работало нормально , тупа через F5 , но я чет проекты создавал и после этого не запускалась консоль